# Let $n \geq 1$ be an odd integer. Show that $D_{2n}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times D_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups, direct-product

Let $n \geq 1$ be an odd integer. Show that $D_{2n}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times D_n$. I define a map $$\phi:D_{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \times D_n$$ by $R \mapsto (0,r^{\frac{n+1}{2}})$ and $M \mapsto(1,m)$. Then I am stuck at showing the map is bijective. By the way, do we need to show that $(0,r^{\frac{n+1}{2}})(1,m)(0,r^{\frac{n+1}{2}})^{-1}=(1,m)$ ? If we can prove this, then what can we conclude?

Comment: $D_5$ is a set which has order $10$. The order of $r$ is 5.

Comment: Nice question, but I think you'd better define $D_{2n}$ as you consider it. This is because we have two notation defining it. In fact, I think $D_{2n}$ here is the same as $D_{4n}$. Thanks

Comment: @Idonknow: related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40365/on-the-centres-of-the-dihedral-groups

Comment: @Idonknow: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415879

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at your map--let's call it $\phi$. I claim that it fails to be surjective. Suppose it **is** surjective, so in particular, $\phi(R^jM^k)=(1,e)$ for some natural $j,k$. Now, $$\phi(R^j)=\phi(R)^j=\bigl(0,r^{\frac{n+1}2}\bigr)^j=\bigl(j\cdot 0,r^{j\cdot\frac{n+1}2}\bigr)=\bigl(0,r^{j\cdot\frac{n+1}2}\bigr)$$ and $$\phi(M^k)=\phi(M)^k=(1,m)^k=(k\cdot 1,m^k)=(k,m^k),$$ so $$\begin{align}(1,e) &= \phi(R^jM^k)\\ &= \phi(R^j)\phi(M^k)\\ &= \bigl(0,r^{j\cdot\frac{n+1}2}\bigr)(k,m^k)\\ &= \bigl(0+k,r^{j\cdot\frac{n+1}2}m^k\bigr)\\ &= \bigl(k,r^{j\cdot\frac{n+1}2}m^k\bigr).\end{align}$$ Then $k$ must be odd (since $1=k$ *modulo* $2$), but if $k$ is odd, then we can't have $r^{j\cdot\frac{n+1}2}m^k=e$, so we have a contradiction.

---

Finding an isomorphism is (in many cases) quite a bit out of our way, but let's go ahead and do it here anyway. Whatever we map $R$ to is going to *have* to have order $2n$ for the map to be injective. (Why?) A convenient choice is $(1,r),$ because $$(0,e)=(1,r)^k=(k,r^k)$$ implies that $k$ is even (since $k=0$ *modulo* $2$) and that $n$ divides $k$ (since $r^k=e$ and $r$ has order $n$), whence $k$ is an integer multiple of $2n$ (since $n$ is odd). Whatever we map $M$ to *can't* be in the subgroup of $\Bbb Z_2\times D_n$ generated by $(1,r)$ (why not?). An easy choice then is $(1,m).$ Now, let's prove surjectivity by showing that every member of a generating set of $\Bbb Z_2\times D_n$ is mapped to by the homomorphism $\Phi:D_{2n}\to\Bbb Z_2\times D_n$ induced by $R\mapsto(1,r),M\mapsto(1,m).$ (Why is this enough?) A nice generating set of $\Bbb Z_2\times D_n$ is $$\bigl\{(1,e),(0,r),(0,m)\bigr\},$$ and it can be determined that $$\Phi(R^n)=(1,e),\;\Phi(R^{n+1})=(0,r),\text{ and }\Phi(R^nM)=(0,m).$$ Since we're dealing with finite groups of the same order, then surjectivity is the same as injectivity, so we're done.

---

The approach above was fairly tedious, and we'd generally like to avoid using it. Instead, consider the following

**Theorem**: Let $G,H,K$ be (multiplicative) groups. Then $G\cong H\times K$ if and only if $G$ has normal subgroups $H',K'$ such that $H'\cong H,K'\cong K,H'\cap K'=\{\text{id}_G\},$ and $$G=H'K':=\{hk:h\in H',k\in K'\}.$$

Proving the above result is a nice exercise (let me know if you want any hints on how to prove the backward direction). It then yields the following

**Corollary**: Let $G,H,K$ be *finite* (multiplicative) groups. Then $G\cong H\times K$ if and only if $G$ has normal subgroups $H',K'$ such that $H'\cong H,K'\cong K,\text{ and }H'\cap K'=\{\text{id}_G\}.$

By the Corollary, we need only find normal subgroups of $D_{2n}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$ and $D_n$, whose intersection is precisely $\{E\}.$ The subgroup generated by $R^2$ and $M$ should do the trick as a subgroup isomorphic to $D_n$ (automatically normal, since it has index $2$), and since $R^n$ has order $2$ and commutes with everything, then the subgroup it generates is normal and isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$.

---

**Edit**: Sadly, the Corollary is false in the form shown above! (Credit to Geralt of Rivia for pointing out the issue.) Another condition is needed. If we add the hypothesis that $\|H\|\cdot\|K\|=\|G\|,$ that gets us the rest of the way.

As far as the specific example goes, since we readily have $\left\|D_{2n}\right\|=2\cdot\left\|D_n\right\|,$ then the adjusted Corollary gets us there.

Comment: condition H'K' = G is missing

Comment: @Geralt: You mean from the Corollary? No, it isn't missing. Rather, it is a consequence of the other conditions, together with the added condition of finiteness.

Comment: But for example $G = S_3$, $H \cong A_3$, $ K \cong \text{id} $, $G, H, K$ satisfy the 3 conditions  and $G$ is not isomorphic to $H \times K$ ?

Comment: Oh, dear! You're quite right. I must have mis-recalled the result. I will check it when I get home and fix it accordingly. My thanks!

Comment: It should be fixed now. Thanks again, @Geralt!

Comment: Hey guys. Can I ask what get's wrong when we try to imply the same proof for even n? Why do we demand n to be odd?

Comment: @Ron: The issue, if I recall correctly, is the *normal* condition. We can demonstrate the existence of a normal subgroup of $D_{2n}$ with the same order as $D_n$ when $n$ is odd, but we can't do this in general when $n$ is even. I believe that $n=4$ is the smallest counterexample.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ron: Slight correction: it's the 2-element subgroups that need not be normal.

Comment: I founded another way to prove that the statement is wrong for even n: it's pretty easy to show that the center of direct product isomorphic to the product of centers.Then, using the order of centers we get contradiction. :)

Comment: Nice approach, @Ron!

Answer (score 5):

Although I don't exactly understand your attempt, you seem to be mapping all rotations to elements of the form $(0,y)$, and all reflections to elements of the form $(1,y)$. This cannot work, since the subgroup of rotations in $D_{2n}$ is not isomorphic to $D_n$ (for instance because it is commutative). One indication of how to define the map is that $D_{2n}$ has a single non-identity element in its centre, namely the half-turn rotation, which is also minus the identity $-I$ (a central symmetry). This element has to map to $(1,0)$, the unique non-identity element in the centre of $\Bbb Z_2\times D_n$.

Here is a geometric way of defining a map $\Bbb Z_2\times D_n\to D_{2n}$. Draw a regular $n$-gon inside a regular $2n$-gon by alternatingly using and not using vertices as one goes around the $2n$-gon. Now every symmetry of the $n$-gon is also a symmetry of the $2n$-gon, and this defines an injective group morphism $f_1:D_n\to D_{2n}$. An injective group morphism $\Bbb Z_2\to D_{2n}$ is given by sending the non-identity element to $-I$ (so the map is $f_2:\overline m\mapsto (-I)^m$). The image of $f_2$ is central in $D_{2n}$, so it commutes with the image $D_n$ of $f_1$, and the two morphisms combine to a morphism $f:\Bbb Z_2\times D_n\cong D_{2n}$ (formally, $f(x,y)=f_1(x)f_2(y)$). Since $-I$ is not in $D_n$, the kernel of $f$ consists of just the identity and $f$ is injective. Both groups have the same cardinality $4n$, so $f$ is in fact an isomorphism (surjectivity is also easy to check directly: if an element of $D_{2n}$ is not a symmetry of the $n$-gon, then it interchanges the chosen and non-chosen vertices, and composing it with $-I$ then gives an element of $D_n$).

The isomorphism $D_{2n}\cong\Bbb Z_2\times D_n$ you were looking for is of course $f^{-1}$. From the above, one can gather the following direct description of $f^{-1}$. Given an element $g\in D_{2n}$ the first component of $f^{-1}(g)$ tells whether or not $g$ preserves the $n$-gon inscribed in the $2n$-gon (the component is correspondingly $\overline0$ respectively $\overline1$). The second component of $f^{-1}(g)$ gives a symmetry of the (chosen) inscribed $n$-gon, defined depending on the first component: when it is $\overline0$, the second component is just the restriction of the action of$~g$, and when it is $\overline1$, the second component is the restriction of the composition of $g$ with the central symmetry$~{-}I$ (which composition preserved the inscribed $n$-gon in this case).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To show $D_{2n} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2\times D_n$, it suffices to find normal subgroups $N_1,N_2$ in $D_{2n}$ such that $N_1\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, $N_2\cong D_n$, $N_1\cap N_2 = \{\operatorname{id}\}$ and $\left|N_1\right|\cdot\left|N_2\right| = \left|D_{2n}\right|$.

Comment: More precisely, $N_1=\{e,r_\pi\}$ and $N_2=D_n$. Am I right?