# Understanding the concept

Tags: group-theory

I have seen the statement-"Kleins four group is isomorphic to the dihedral group of order 4".
I am not getting how to get the dihedral of order 4 as for the dihedral having order four it should be regular 2-gon. What are the elements of this dihedral?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415994/is-there-a-dihedral-group-of-order-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of *defining dihedral groups*, there is no loss, if we think of regular $2$-gon as follows: consider a circle, and fix two opposite end-points $P,Q$. Then there are two paths from $P$ to $Q$, both of same length, and we can call it regular $2$-gon.

Then this regular $2$-gon has four symmetries: let the points $P,Q$ be like south-pole and north-pole. Then vertical reflection, horizontal reflection, $180^o$ rotation around center, together with identity will give the Klein-4 group.